# Change Default Page in ASP.NET Core Razor Page to Login Page

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

I am changing Default Page from /Home/Index to /Identity/Account/Login using ASP.NET Core Razor Page but it is always loading /Home page as default page.

```
services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.Clear();
                    options.AllowAreas = true;
                    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Login", "/Identity/Account/Login");
                });
```

It should load the Login Page Model as default page. Please help me to solve above problem. Waiting for your quick response.

Comment: Do you use conventional or attribute routing?

Answer (score 8):

To map your site's root to the `/Identity/Account/Login` page in ASP.Net Core (v2.1 and above) you can follow these instructions:

1. Undo the changes you've made in the `ConfigureServices()` method. (I.e. `.AddRazorPagesOptions(...)`)
2. Change  the `@page` declaration at the top of the *Login.cshtml* template file to `@page "/"`
3. If you haven't already, delete the *Index.cshtml* and *Index.cs* page files.

Step 1 is for cleaning up.

Step 2 is to configure the *Login* to the root path `/`. (more info [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes))

Step 3 is necessary because if the *Index* page files are not deleted, they will be mapped by convention to the root path and will conflict with the changes in step 2. This will throw a `AmbiguousMatchException` when you browse to the root path.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me using .net core 3.1

Answer (score 3):

The arguments of `AddAreaPageRoute` are `areaName`, `pageName`, `route`

For setting the default page in area `Identity` to `/IdentityAccount/Login` you would have to call

```
options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Identity/Account/Login", "");
```

If you want to set the page-wide default page you should call

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/Account/Login", "");
```

The *default page* is at route `""`

Comment: I have tried both the option but still it is loading Home page as default page instead of Login Page.

Comment: Hard to tell from here without seeing the complete project.
What do you enter in the browser address bar? Are you calling any other API that might be setting the default URL?

Comment: @GKB try deleting the original Index page.